# What does it mean that a set S tautologically implies wff $\tau$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

What does it mean that a set $S$ tautologically implies wff $ \tau$ ? 
in Enderton introduction to mathematical logic , in page 23 ,

it define that a set $S$ tautologically implies wff $ \tau$ iff every truth assigment for the sentence symbols in $S$ and $ \tau$ that satisfies every member of $S$ also satisfies $ \tau$

i have some questions related to this definition ,

does this definition require that the elements of the wff $ \tau$ are in $S$ ? 
or not ??

also , i think that giving an example about this definition is great !

if this definition doesn't require that the elements of $ \tau $ are in $S$ , 
does this mean that if we made a set $S$ whose intersection with the wff $ \tau$ if the empty set then S tautologically implies $ \tau$ in general ??

i find that the definition is not so clear for me !

thanx !

Comment: What are the elements of a wff?  If (p->q) is a wff, are "p", "q" and "->" the elements of (p->q)?

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood ,wff means that the expression " which is a finite sequence of the symblos " is well formed formula .. so wff is abbrevation .

Comment: Usually I've seen wff as an abbreviation for well-formed formula, which means a certain sequence of symbols that follows rules.  Usually (p->q) is a wff, but p(->q) is not a wff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to understand the definition like this. Pool all the propositional letters (sentence symbols) which occur in wffs in the set $S$ together with the (same or different!) propositional letters which occur in $\tau$. So if $S$ contains the wffs $P$ and $(\neg P \lor Q)$, and $\tau$ is $(Q \lor R)$, then the relevant letters that occur somewhere or other are $P, Q,  R$. Now consider valuations $V$ of these letters. $S \vdash \tau$ iff for every such $V$, if $V$ makes all the wffs in $S$ true, it makes $\tau$ true.

So, for example, we indeed have

$$\{P, (\neg P \lor Q)\} \vDash (Q \lor R),$$

even though the conclusion contains a propositional letter which isn't in the premisses. (And that's what we want! For the conclusion plainly *does* logically follow from the premisses!)

Second, suppose though that none of the propositional letters in $S$ are in $\tau$. To take a simple case, suppose $S$ contains the wff $P$, and $\tau$ is $Q$. Then we would *not* have

$$\{P\} \vDash Q$$

because the valuation $P \Rightarrow T$, $Q \Rightarrow F$ makes the sole premiss true and the supposed conclusion false, showing this isn't a tautological entailment.

In fact we'll have the following result. If $S$ and $\tau$ lack propositional letters in common,

$$S \vDash \tau$$

holds just when $\tau$ is already a tautology, or when the wffs $S$ are contradictory (cannot all be true together), *but not otherwise*.

Comment: very clear explaination .. thanks :)